# Adding Random Number to Uploaded File

Tags: php, ajaxuploader

I'm using Valum's Ajax-Uploader script to upload files to my server. Because there's a good chance of the uploaded files have the same name I add a random number to the filename. The problem is that the ajax uploader is returning the original filename into the `input[type=text]` instead of the new filename with the random number added. I've tried `echo $file;` instead of `echo "success";` , but all that happens is that the file is uploaded, and the script returns with the pop-up error.

```
jQuery(function() {
    var url = "http://example.com/uploads/samples/";
    var button = jQuery('#up');
    new AjaxUpload(button, {
        action: 'upload.php',
        name: 'upload',
        autoSubmit: true,
        onSubmit: function(file, ext) {
            // do stuff while file is uploading
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            if (response === "success") {
                $('input[type=text]').val(url + file);
            } else {
                jAlert('Something went wrong!', 'Error!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = '/path/to/uploaddir/'; 
    $file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

     if($_FILES['file']['name']) {
      $file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $file);
      $rand = rand(0000,9999);

      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $rand . $file)) { 
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. In you code you can even just use `jQuery(function($) {` in the first line and then use `$` in the function.

Comment: Why are you using `addslashes()`? There is no need to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. OP updated with the proper upload.php code. The script is working, but the file that is uploaded has the random number attached, but the filename that outputs into `$('input[type=text]').text(url + file);` is missing the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client code and server code exist completely independently of each other. Basically, your JavaScript code has no way of knowing what your PHP code just did. `url` doesn't update automatically when you change it in the PHP file.

An alternate solution would be to have your PHP code echo the new filename, or echo an error message.

For example:

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $rand . $file)) {   
    // Everything went well! Echo the dollar sign ($) plus the new file name
    echo '$' . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $rand . $file;   
} else {  
    echo "error";  
}  
?>
```

**JS**

```
onComplete: function(file, response) { 
    // If the first character of the response is the "$" sign
    if (response.substring(0,1) == "$") { 
        $('input[type=text]').val(response.substring(1));
    } else { 
        jAlert('Something went wrong!', 'Error!'); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('input[type=text]').text(url + file);
```

To

```
$('input[type=text]').val(url + file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using date and time to create a unique random number.
You can use following function in your code, I am fully trusted on this function because I already use this in my project.

```
`
    /**
    * This function return unique string as a key 
    */
    public static function getUniqueKey(){      
        $currentDateTime = date("YmdHisu");
        return $currentDateTime . BTITTools::createRandomString(3);
    }
`
```

@ [My Code Programs](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/)