# PHP JQuery Form Validation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

If I want to create a form and validate it. If the validation is successful, I will insert this data into a mysql database. Is the best way to do this is to create a form via HTML, then validate it in jQuery and submit the data from the post method through PHP into a mysql database?

Any simple examples are welcome (submit firstname and lastname where both field must be typed in).

I tried some examples but they reload the page when the validation is false and you lose all the data in the textbox fields.

Comment: Validation using JavaScript is always helpful, but validation MUST be done server-side if it's to be considered reliable. JavaScript validation can always be bypassed by a user. Just search for "jquery form validation" and "php form validation" for a wide variety of solutions.

Comment: that is what i attempted. I had validation using jQuery but putting php statements in the if statements doesn't work. Either way, the php statement will execute and ignores the if/else statements.

Comment: We can't possibly help you further without seeing specific code that's causing you a specific problem.

Comment: are you want to validate your form with php or jquery?

Comment: then this will be done with the use of jquery. See this link,it may help you http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/#.UH65TW9Fx2E

Answer (score 1):

Example from my project:

```
 function initContactForm(){
        $('#contact-form').validate({
            errorClass: 'invalid-input',
            validClass: 'valid-input',
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                sername: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                company_name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    minlength: 7
                },
                mail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(data){
                $('#loading').ajaxStart(function(){
                    $(this).show('fast');
                    $('.register-btn').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#loading').ajaxStop(function(){
                    $(this).hide('fast')
                });
                $('#contact-form').ajaxSubmit(function(html){
                    $('.control-group').animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 500, function(){ opacity: 1 });
                    $('#formHandler').html(html);
                    $('#formHandler').show('fast');
                    $('.alert').bind('close', function(){
                        $('#contact-form').each(function(){ this.reset(); });
                        $('.controls input').removeClass();
                        $('.controls textarea').removeClass();
                        $('.register-btn').show('fast');
                        $('.control-group').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500, function(){ opacity: 0.2 });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a server side verification is still necessary juste before insert/update statement to avoid corrupted datas.

You can have a Php script called with ajax. In that way, you will not have the page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you accept user data, you *should* validate it using JavaScript, and you **must** validate it using PHP. Advanced users can disable JavaScript in their browser, meaning that they can ignore any JavaScript or jQuery validation.

For example, this page will validate the data using both client-side JavaScript *and* PHP:

```
<?php
//  index.php
$firstname_val = '';
$firstname_text = '';

//  if the firstname field isn't blank...
if(len(trim($_POST['firstname'])) > 0) {
    //  insert into your database
//  if the firstname field _is_ blank...
} else {
    //  load the page
    $firstname_val = 'This value cannot be blank';
      //  store the old value and re-insert it into the input field below
      $firstname_text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']);
}

?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#go").click(function(e) {
        //  if the Firstname input isn't blank...
        if($("#firstname_field").val().trim().length > 0) {
            //  clear the error message
            $("#firstname_val").text("");

            //  submit the form
            $("#form").submit();
        //  otherwise, if it is blank...
        } else {
            //  prevent the form submission
            e.preventDefault();
            //  show an error message
            $("#firstname_val").text("This value cannot be blank");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="form">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname_field" value="<?php echo $firstname_text;?>" /><br />
<span style="color:#f00;" id="firstname_val"><?php echo $firstname_val; ?></span><br />
<input type="submit" value="Go" id="go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works! But if the user disabled javascript, this code will use the php validation. However, if firstname is blank, wouldn't the form submit and any text entered will be lost (page refreshed)?

Comment: I've updated the answer slightly. The PHP will now store the `$_POST['firstname']` as a variable, then echo it back out into the `firstname` field.

Comment: one more thing. I think ajax would be the best option to submit data to mysql from that javascript function you made.

Comment: In that case, I'd put the validation into another function. If it validates, then return true. Otherwise, return false. Then, replace the inside of the `$("#go").click(...` with: a call to your new validation function; a jQuery AJAX function that can read the server's response data. You then need to make your PHP print a success message, or an error message, and find a way to display this on your page. You can see an example of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846552/adding-random-number-to-uploaded-file/12847583